# What are the two unnamed parts that came with new Char-Broil gas grill?

Tags: propane-grill

I just purchased a new Char-Broil gas grill today. It came with a manual, which I read before doing anything else. What puzzles me are two unidentified parts that are not mentioned in the product manual. Does anyone know what these two parts are called and what their purpose is?

Photo #1: Small metal item that came in bag with manual.

[image: Small metal item]

Photo #2: Metal piece hanging by chain from left side of grill.

[image: item hanging from left side of grill]

Here it the item in better context.

[image: item in context]

Comment: Have you checked the [manufacturer’s website](https://www.charbroil.co.nz/tips/how-light-your-gas-grill-manually)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Photo #2, item on chain, is a match holder. Photo #1 is possibly the holder for a grease cup.  I would go to the link shared by Spagirl above to see if you can track it down.

Answer (score 6):

I just bought the same grill earlier this week. The second item is a match holder as moscafj mentioned. The first is used when assembling the bottom of the cabinet: the two pins slot into a pair of holes on each wheel mount, which locks the wheel in place allowing you to screw the wheel in. After the wheel is in, you remove the pin to allow it to freely rotate.